# Is it possible to configure Featherlight popups to show only once per user?

Tags: featherlight.js

Looking to configure featherlight.js to show only once per user (ie. if user loads the page again they will not see it). With thanks, Cas.

Comment: Colleague found solution:

Answer (score 1):

Colleague found a solution...

```
welcomeLightbox: function () {
    'use strict';
    if ($.cookie('welcomeLightboxShown') == null) {
      $.featherlight($('#mylightbox'), {});
    }
    $('.featherlight-close').click(function() {
      // $.cookie('welcomeLightboxShown', 'true', { path: '/' });
      $.cookie('welcomeLightboxShown', 'true', { expires: 365, path: '/' });
    });
  },
```

Comment: Ok solution. Best to use the `afterClose` callback to set the cookie, though. If the user presses escape, for instance, your code won't set the cookie.